# how to use docusign api to intergrate docusign electronic sign functionality in php existing website

Tags: docusignapi

I've a PHP website, my client have a document looks like a agreement he wants me to create a form put name in that form and use same document and send that from my website I know I can do this by Docusign API but i want to get knowledge how I can use the docusign rest api.

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can do what we call [embedded signing](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-in-app-embedded/), by using the following code:

```
    private function make_envelope($args)
    {
        $demo_docs_path = __DIR__ . '/../public/demo_documents/';
        $content_bytes = file_get_contents($demo_docs_path . $GLOBALS['DS_CONFIG']['doc_pdf']);
        $base64_file_content = base64_encode($content_bytes);
        # Create the document model
        $document = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Document([ # create the DocuSign document object
            'document_base64' => $base64_file_content,
            'name' => 'Example document', # can be different from actual file name
            'file_extension' => 'pdf', # many different document types are accepted
            'document_id' => 1 # a label used to reference the doc
        ]);
        # Create the signer recipient model
        $signer = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer([ # The signer
            'email' => $args['signer_email'], 'name' => $args['signer_name'],
            'recipient_id' => "1", 'routing_order' => "1",
            # Setting the client_user_id marks the signer as embedded
            'client_user_id' => $args['signer_client_id']
        ]);
        # Create a sign_here tab (field on the document)
        $sign_here = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere([ # DocuSign SignHere field/tab
            'anchor_string' => '/sn1/', 'anchor_units' => 'pixels',
            'anchor_y_offset' => '10', 'anchor_x_offset' => '20'
        ]);
        # Add the tabs model (including the sign_here tab) to the signer
        # The Tabs object wants arrays of the different field/tab types
        $signer->settabs(new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs(['sign_here_tabs' => [$sign_here]]));
        # Next, create the top level envelope definition and populate it.
        $envelope_definition = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition([
            'email_subject' => "Please sign this document sent from the PHP SDK",
            'documents' => [$document],
            # The Recipients object wants arrays for each recipient type
            'recipients' => new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Recipients(['signers' => [$signer]]),
            'status' => "sent" # requests that the envelope be created and sent.
        ]);
        return $envelope_definition;
    }
    
    $envelope_args = $args["envelope_args"];
    
    # Create the envelope request object
    $envelope_definition = $this->make_envelope($args["envelope_args"]);
    $envelope_api = $this->clientService->getEnvelopeApi();
    
    # Call Envelopes::create API method
    # Exceptions will be caught by the calling function
    $config = new \DocuSign\eSign\Configuration();
    $config->setHost($args['base_path']);
    $config->addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $args['ds_access_token']);
    $api_client = new \DocuSign\eSign\client\ApiClient($config);
    $envelope_api = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi($api_client);
    $results = $envelope_api->createEnvelope($args['account_id'], $envelope_definition);
    
    $envelope_id = $results->getEnvelopeId();
# Create the Recipient View request object
$authentication_method = 'None'; # How is this application authenticating
# the signer? See the `authenticationMethod' definition
# https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient
$recipient_view_request = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientViewRequest([
    'authentication_method' => $authentication_method,
    'client_user_id' => $envelope_args['signer_client_id'],
    'recipient_id' => '1',
    'return_url' => $envelope_args['ds_return_url'],
    'user_name' => $envelope_args['signer_name'], 'email' => $envelope_args['signer_email']
]);
# Obtain the recipient_view_url for the signing ceremony
# Exceptions will be caught by the calling function
 $results = $envelope_api->createRecipientView($args['account_id'], $envelope_id,
     $recipient_view_request);
 return ['envelope_id' => $envelope_id, 'redirect_url' => $results['url']];
```

Comment: but how user will able to do sign?? can you please explain this??

Comment: where i can include the files?

Comment: I suggest you try our quickstart, it will work for you and you can then see how it works

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/

Comment: This will create a personalized ZIP file with authentication and everything and will just work for you.

Comment: but it includes the composer etc which i don't have so I've to do a lot of work

Comment: it is showing error because i don't find the autoload.php fille

Comment: what web server are you using XAMPP? IIS?

Comment: `Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\Supplierforhire-php\public/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Supplierforhire-php\public\index.php on line 9`

Comment: Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Supplierforhire-php\public/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Supplierforhire-php\public\index.php on line 9

Comment: i'M USING XAMPP

Comment: can i simply create a template of document in docusign and send it to users directly with custom fields to their email by my website using api?

Comment: yes, you can do a lot of things, but you need to get something working first to ensure you figured out how to call any API at all.

Comment: i just want to make things simple i already created a envelope with template of document i want to just resent it to different user's email by api can i do it in a simplest way?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZHxmhijol8 see this video

Comment: you can do anything with PHP and API once you get it working.

Comment: I've api experience before but I'm really confused about this one because they don't have  a proper direct api call.

Comment: what do you mean by "direct API call"?

Comment: it means a direct url like api.docusign.com where i can put my envelope id and account id and it does the job?

Comment: docusign/esign-client v6.0.0-rc requires php >=7.4 -> your php version (7.3.18) does not satisfy that requirement.

Comment: i installed the composer but i got this error

Comment: This "direct URL" option is insecure, as it doesn't use authentication.

Comment: another option is you can use postman, follow the instructions in here - https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-please-mr-postman

Comment: can you tell me about error because composer have latest 7.3.18 on it.

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\Supplierforhire-php\public\index.php this is where your issue is, this file is not related to DocuSign, not sure what it is. You need to have a clean server to know the issue is unrelated. Can you maybe use Docker? it's much easier

Comment: did you run "composer install"

Comment: but i will use docker i have to shift my whole php website to docker because currently it is simply hosted.

Comment: please just tell me how i can import `make_envelope` files for this function so that i can send directly

Comment: can you use any other lang? node maybe? that's one of the easiest langs. If you can - use node.js in the tool to generate your code, it's super easy and works all the time.

Comment: if you just want a link in your site - maybe use PowerForms? you can do that without writing any code - https://www.docusign.com/features-and-benefits/features/powerforms

Comment: did you have composer installed for PHP? Are you on Windows or Linux or Mac? where did you install composer from?

Comment: yes i have installed the composer in the path level.. and I'm using windows

Comment: as far as question related to technology my website is in php core so i can't switch now to node that's the reason and i have to do this by code and automatically by my website.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm unable to resolve your issue at this time. You can file a support ticket with our support group and they can help you further. Please visit support.docusign.com

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'string' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in C:\xampp\htdocs\SFH-php\vendor\docusign\esign-client\src\Api\EnvelopesApi.php on line 41

Comment: are you just using the code that was downloaded in the ZIP file as-is? or did you modify it? or have your own code?

Comment: I am just using there own code and it is working fine but i want to simply make it works for live project but it is not sending anything to email

Comment: I state that i want to send a document to the user to their email with some custom fields like I want i can add the name of my user on the document how i can manage this thing by Docusign API.. I already have working code of node-js

Comment: but i don't saw any option where i can do what i state above.

Comment: what is not sending anything to email? live project? how did you create live project? I want to help you but there's too much confusion about what you're doing, what works, what doesn't, what code you're using etc.

Comment: i am not doing anything live i just downloaded quickstart project from your website but i want to do it live in my website how i can do it please tell me this.. how i can convert demo project to live work?

Comment: going live, aha. Yes, to go live you must follow the instructions in here - https://developers.docusign.com/platform/go-live/

Comment: ok but even i don't see what i want to do ?

Comment: i want to send a document to different user but i want all the time user have to sign and type his name etc in the document so i want to see from where i can do it in demo because i don't understand.

Sorry for asking too much.

Comment: that feature is called "sign in each location" and I wrote a blog about it here - https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-sign-each-location

Comment: Hi i read your article but you didn't defined from where we get Signer? and SignHere?? we have to add just models file or have to do something different?

Comment: If you have PHP code that is already working (you said you did) then you just have to modify it the way I explained in this blog. The objects for the models are needed, yes.

Comment: i just need to include the classes of models in that blog codes file?

Comment: Start with the working code you downloaded from quickstart and then modify it based on the blog post.